# Oracle BI Publisher: The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke

Tags: oracle, publisher

I installed BI Publisher Desktop and try login to BI Publisher Server (via Microsoft Excel plugin). 5 seconds later, I got an error: "Please contact administrator for your userid/password". In this case, the authorization in the browser runs fine.
I ran Wireshark and catch request/response:

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <loginResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService">
            <loginReturn>43908A031CE6DC73D61D77D39CB10948</loginReturn>
        </loginResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Server.NoService</faultcode>
            <faultstring>The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke!  targetService is v2/SecurityService</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">MSKORABI03</ns2:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I fix this error? Thanks in advance for your help!